# using declarations not defined when including cinttypes

Tags: c++

When I try to include cinttypes, I get errors that a bunch of stuff is undefined.  It seems to be occurring on using declarations, such as:

```
/path/to/file/cinttypes:row:col: error '::imaxdiv_t' has not been declared in this scope using ::imaxdiv_t;
```

but looking at this, isn't cinttypes the very header that is supposed to define this?

Edit: I think I finally found the correct compiler version for this, it seems to be gcc 9.5

Comment: Yes, `<cinttypes>` is supposed to define `std::imaxdiv_t`, and if it's producing an error that `::imaxdiv_t` (which is typically used as the implementation for the `std` version) has not been defined that's an error in the header. What compiler are you using?

Comment: @PeteBecker I'm pretty sure our yocto build system is running gcc... I don't really know a lot about this particular build system... you think it's related to the compiler then though?

Comment: The compiler comes with its own version of the standard library; problems in the standard headers usually come from incorrect setup, and sorting that out requires knowing the compiler and the compiler version.

Comment: @PeteBecker gcc 7.5 I think for this particular thing...

Comment: Have you tried std::imaxdiv_t? I don't believe that ::imaxdiv_t is required to be provided in C++, though it may be in many(?) implementations.

Comment: @AviBerger So, I never actually use it in my code.  But the header itself can't seem to find it...  I just needed the PRIx## types for printf statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed

```
#include <cinttypes>
```

to

```
#include <inttypes.h>
```

And this fixed it.  Might be a compiler bug, but the c header seems to work fine oddly.

Update: I also needed to #include <stdint.h> above #include <inttypes.h> in some cases as inttypes.h depends on stdint.h but stdint.h isn't included by inttypes.h, at least on my system, so using

```cpp
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
```

produced more reliable results.

Comment: `<cinttypes>` provides `std::imaxdiv_t`.  It may or may not provide `::imaxdiv_t`.  The reverse is true for `inttypes.h`

Comment: @BenVoigt Well, my implementation tries to define std::imaxdiv_t in <cinttypes>, however it fails as ::imaxdiv_t is undefined.  This is clearly a bug in the implementation.  However it seems that including <inttypes.h> gets around this chicken and egg problem.  If I really cared I could probably do a #include <cinttypes> after this, but I don't actually need the variables from the file anyway, what I need are the macros so I don't care about the variable namespaces for my purposes.  Adding context with this comment for others though if they find a similar issue in their implementation.